# Run Go Gin service on production server

Tags: go, web-applications

I have a web site that is hosted by GoDaddy. I have developed a Go Gin-based web service that I have tested on my local machine and it works exactly as I expect. I have uploaded my app to my website's server, using the cPanel application (provided by GoDaddy), and have run my application using SSH. It seems to run fine from SSH and throws no errors, and even outputs to the terminal some start-up information that shows me it is working. I should say that I have compiled it for amd64 linux, as that is what my production server is running. I've also uploaded all of the associated files, e.g. style.css, templates, etc. However when I navigate to the various handlers in the browser, using my domain as the base, I get nothing but a 'This page does not seem to exist' error. That is, on my local machine, I can navigate to say, 'http://localhost:8080/register_license', but when I navigate to 'http://example-domain.com/register_license', I get the page does not exist error.

I have spent the day searching the Internet for the issue without much luck. I'm very new to web programming, although I have been programming for many years now, and I suspect that I'm doing something wrong in the deployment process that a proper web programmer just takes for granted in knowing. Something like perhaps having to place the app in some specially designated directory that I am unaware of. Everything that I've read so far about deploying Gin apps indicate that you just need to upload the app file and run it on the production server and so I know that I'm missing something very basic here. I apologize if this is a very basic web programming question but I'm not sure what else to do at this point.

Comment: Have you done [DNS mapping](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-dns) for your server IP to `http://example-domain.com`?

Comment: @nipuna No, I'm afraid that I'm not familiar with that but I'll read over the link that you sent me and try to figure it out. Thanks for the tip.